# Typoscript and Cache

Tags: caching, typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

In my Typoscript I have a `COA` Object in which I gather some GET Parameters together:

```
lib.gets = COA
lib.gets {
    10 = TEXT
    10.stdWrap.data = GP:param1
    20 = TEXT
    20.value = ,
    30 = TEXT
    30.stdWrap.data = GP:param2
}
```

After that I use this in a `USER_INT` Object. (USER_INT is the same as USER but does not get cached).

```
lib.mystuff = USER_INT
lib.mystuff {
    pseudocode < lib.gets
}
```

When I then output this 2 Objects in my template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.gets" />
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.mystuff" />
```

`lib.mystuff` is right and allways up-to-date. But `lib.gets` is cached and stays the same even if the Get Parameters change. I know I just could use a `COA_INT` but my question is, why can `lib.mystuff` be up-to-date when `lib.gets` is cached? It looks like in typoscript `lib.gets` is not cached but then in the template it is.

Comment: "It looks like in typoscript lib.gets is not cached but then in the template it is.". That can not be true. How did you test it? Remember always to test caching issues from another browser where you are not logged to backend.

Comment: @Krystian Yea I am confused about this. I output the 2 typoscript objects. the first `lib.gets`its just a Text with some Ids in it. In the frontend it stays the same, even if I change the GET Parameters. the `lib.mystuff` uses a `userFunc` with the Ids from `lib.gets` and gives other output depending on this Ids. So in the frontend the output of `lib.mystuff` changes with other Ids, the output of `lib.gets` does not.

Comment: You copy the TS configuration to your lib.mystuff. This does not contain the values of the get parameters. So the configuration is parsed/executed in two different contexts. With <. you could keep a reference including the evaluated values from get

Comment: The *_INT means it will be not cached. So if you change lib.mystuff = USER_INT to lib.mystuff = USER then it will be not cached also.

Answer (score 0):

Try `lib.gets = COA_INT` instead of `COA`.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/CoaAndCoaInt/Index.html